# Is there a way to override as_json in single table inherited class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :meta_type
  scope :doctors, -> { where(meta_type: 'Doctor') }
  scope :patients, -> { where(meta_type: 'Patient') }

  def as_json(options={})
    super( (options || {}).merge({ :methods => [:profile_url]}))
  end

  def profile_url
    self.image(:small)
  end
end
```

Doctor and Patient classes each inherit from User class:

```
class Doctor < User
  has_many :patients, :through #other irrelevant code  
end

class Patient < User
  has_one :doctor  
  has_many :conditions 
end
```

What I want to be able to do is also override `as_json` in my Patient class for Patient specific methods. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same as you're doing with User?

```
class Patient < User
  has_one :doctor  
  has_many :conditions

  def as_json(options={})
    super( (options || {}).merge({ :methods => [:your_patient_methods]}))
  end

end
```

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work since I am inheriting the Patient class from the User class. The User class as_json method is only called